# Tabular Query to Compare Measures Across Dates

Tags: sql, dax, ssas-tabular

I've got a number of rows and I want to calculate the difference per date.

So say I have the following:

[Date]       [Transaction Number]    [Value]

1 Jan 16  1                                     1000

2 Jan 16  1                                     980

I then want a fact that for every row will compare the value with the measure from the previous date.

So If I have a measure on SUM(Value) for the current date, I basically want SUM(CurrentDate) - SUM(PreviousDate) to see the movement.

A couple of things to note:

1. There will actually be a couple of comparisons: previous date, previous month end, previous year end.
2. I want this as a calculated measure not column so that I do not need to filter on the transaction number in the previous period.

What I've tried but it just comes up empty:

```
Previous Value :=CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value])) - CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value]), FILTER(Table, Table[Date] = PreviousDay(Table[Date])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot tell why your measure didn't work, but following should:

```
Previous Value := CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value]) - CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value]), PREVIOUSDAY(Table[date])))
```

Comment: Would that still work if you filter only for the latest day in excel? I.e. only show the latest date and it's calc for the previous day?

Comment: I think so, you should give it a go. Never tried it in excel though.